# how to make validation for special symbols ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am developing MVC application.

In the application there is a mobile field. 
I want to allow Numbers and +,-,(,) characters to be inserted. 
How to write the validation for this ?

Right now I have only below code.

```
   [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Mobile can accept maximum 15 characters.")]
   public string Mobile { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't know how to include the `+ - ( )` symbols, but this will only allow numbers: `[RegularExpression(@"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]?[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers Are Allowed")]` You'll need to change the regex part `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]?[0-9]` to a regex that will include the symbols you want. Hope that will help you on your search.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression validator.

```
[RegularExpression(@"Pattern", ErrorMessage = "Error Message")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
^[\+\-\(\)0-9]{10,15}$
```

Should do the trick.

Use that pattern with the RegularExpression Attribute

Regards

Si